# How to use requiredTrue on ion-checkbox (template-driven)

Tags: angular, validation, ionic3

I have the following checkbox that needs validation to check that it has been checked. The below however always validate successfully. I believe `requiredTrue` needs to be used, but I get this error:

> Can't bind to 'requiredTrue' since it isn't a known property of
>   'ion-checkbox'.

```
  <ion-item text-wrap color="bright">
    <ion-label>I confirm my details are correct.</ion-label>
    <ion-checkbox name="confirmedAccountDetails" [(ngModel)]="data.confirmedAccountDetails" #confirmedAccountDetails="ngModel" [required]="data.requiresConfirmation" ></ion-checkbox>
  </ion-item>
```

How can I validate this checkbox as checked with template-driven forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a workaround, instead of using `required` or `requiredTrue`

I used: **`[disabled]="!data.requiresConfirmation" pattern="true"`**

```
  <ion-item text-wrap color="bright">
    <ion-label>I confirm my details are correct.</ion-label>
    <ion-checkbox name="confirmedAccountDetails" [(ngModel)]="data.confirmedAccountDetails" #confirmedAccountDetails="ngModel" [disabled]="!data.requiresConfirmation" pattern="true" ></ion-checkbox>
  </ion-item>
```

This prevents validation while disabled and expects the value to be `'true'` when enabled.

The only set back is the validation reason is pattern and not required.